sendKeys command doesn't work on VM from AWS selenium+java
I have a test suite with java+selenium and I have an issue with a payment sandbox. The issue occurs only when I excute the test on VM provided by AWS. I have a login page for the payment and sendKeys("text") command doesn't send any keys. I tried with:
    WebElement loginEmailField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='loginId']"));
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='email@gmail.com';", loginEmailField);

and with this it works, the text is there in the field, but the loging button doesn't trigger correctly (it doesn't do anything).
I also want to mention that the sendKeys works fine when I excute the test on my own machine.
also tried with:
    getActions().moveToElement(loginEmailField).
                    sendKeys(loginEmailField, "email@gmail.com").
                    perform();

but this again doesn't send the keys on the vm.
What do you suggest to try?

Have you tried loginEmailField.sendKeys("email@gamil.com");?

@Shawn yes this what I tried loginEmailField.sendKeys("email@gamil.com"); this works locally, but it doesn't work on vm
